# Select only the text in the line without leading and trailing whitespace

Tags: vim

I know about pressing `V` to select the entire line in Vim. How do I select only the text in the line and not the entire span of it.

So far I have been pressing `home` then `w` then `v` then `end` which is not very snappy.
I'm looking for a way to do that in one swoop.

#### A visualization of what I'm trying to achieve

###### (the '-' character represents what is selected in Visual mode):

Using Shift + V:

```
--------------------------------------
    int n = 0;
```

What I want:

```
    ----------                                              
    int n = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remap V with:

```
:nnoremap V ^vg_
```

^ moves to the first non-whitespace character of the line

v puts you in character mode visual mode

g_ moves you to the last non-whitespace character of the line

Comment: `V` is not a "mapping" so this is not a "remapping". Besides, how is OP going to do `V`, now?

Comment: @romainl Everything is a mapping!  If the OP wants a different keybinding to provide the behavior that V is bound (mapped) to by default, they can provide a different mapping.

Comment: No. `V` is not a mapping so it can't be "remapped" or "unmapped" or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: so straightforward thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no single-character command for that, but any combination of `^` and `g_` will do:

```
^vg_
vg_o^
v^og_
```

Adding the following lines to your `vimrc` will give you the `il` pseudo-text object that you can use like a built-in one: `vil`, `yil`, `dil`, etc.

```
xnoremap il g_o^
onoremap il :<C-u>normal vil<CR>
```

How it works:

- We define a custom visual mode mapping that:

  1. extends the visual selection to the last printable character of the line with `:help g_`,
  2. moves the cursor to the other end of the visual selection with `:help v_o`,
  3. extends the visual selection to the first printable character of the line with `:help ^`.

  It can be used like a built-in motion:

  ```
  vil     " visually select text of current line
  ```
- Then we use that visual mode mapping in an operator-pending mode mapping, which allows us to do:

  ```
  yil     " yank text of current line
  dil     " delete text of current line
  g?il    " rot13 text of current line
  etc.
  ```

PROs:

- idiomatic
- mnemonic
- cheap
- trivial to understand/implement
- doesn't override any existing command

CONs:

- you may miss it if you use a Vim without it

---

FWIW, there are more [where it comes from](https://gist.github.com/romainl/c0a8b57a36aec71a986f1120e1931f20#file-pseudo-text-objects-vim-L13).